# how can i solve this problem amorphous/amorphous.cc:89:15: error: ‘rqueue’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: ns2

how can i solve this problem. ( i refereed to site http://nile.wpi.edu/NS/  i want to extend that example.)

amorphous : i have done all off step and then i have to ran make  and finally while running make i face with error

```
amorphous/amorphous.cc:89:15: error: ‘rqueue’ was not declared in this scope 
    int stat = rqueue.command(argc,argv);
make: *** [amorphous/amorphous.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Please post minimum piece of code so that we replicate what you are facing

Comment: Amorphous etc. https://sourceforge.net/projects/posalgorithms/files/?source=directory : Sketchy code. ... 12 almost identical templates for "possible protocols". INFO https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/amorphous%7Csort:date/ns-users/Y_zroEPmAjA/M-qBnituCQAJ ... Pos-Algo-ns2_info.txt https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9bpi1ilo72q7il/Pos-Algo-ns2_info.txt?dl=0 -